# ReentrantLock - Concurrent money transfer operation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, reentrantlock

While I was reading some concurrency code samples on the internet I found this one (money transfer operation between 2 bank accounts):

```
class Account {
     double balance;
     int id;
     public Account(int id, double balance){
          this.balance = balance;
          this.id = id;
     }
     void withdraw(double amount){
          balance -= amount;
     } 
     void deposit(double amount){
          balance += amount;
     }
}
class Main{
     public static void main(String [] args){
           final Account a = new Account(1,1000);
           final Account b = new Account(2,300);
           Thread a = new Thread(){
                 public void run(){
                     transfer(a,b,200);
                 }
           };
           Thread b = new Thread(){
                 public void run(){
                     transfer(b,a,300);
                 }
           };
           a.start();
           b.start();
     }
```

And this piece of code that deals with the concurrency issue with the use of ReentrantLock:

```
private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(); //Addition to the Account class

public static void transfer(Account from, Account to, double amount)
{
       while(true)
        {
          if(from.lock.tryLock()){
            try { 
                if (to.lock.tryLock()){
                   try{
                       from.withdraw(amount);
                       to.deposit(amount);
                       break;
                   } 
                   finally {
                       to.lock.unlock();
                   }
                }
           }
           finally {
                from.lock.unlock();
           }

           Thread.sleep(someRandomTimeToPreventLiveLock);
        }
 }
```

My question is: shouldn't the Acount's withdraw() and deposit() methods be somehow protected (synchronized or locked with the ReentrantLock field) for this example to work? Isn't it possible for other thread to creep in and invoke withdraw or deposit method? Also, what if there's a getBalance() method? Should it be protected too (synchronized or locked with the ReentrantLock)?

Comment: whether both piece of code are part of `Account` class ?

Comment: IMHO, this peace of code is just to show how to make the `transfer` method thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

(1) You make your class thread-safe meaning that any operation on any instance of this class is guarded by some internal mechanism and is absolutely safe in a multithreading environment. The caller side shouldn't care about thread-safety.

That's what I would prefer here. As a consumer of your API, I would except both `Account#withdraw` and `Account#deposit` to be self-sufficient, so no extra actions would be required.

That's how a good API looks to me.

(2) You place the responsibility of providing correctness and thread-safety on the caller side. You don't care how it's going to be achieved.

That's how your snippets currently work. The method `transfer` is thread-safe, but it doesn't make the account operations such.

Comment: So to follow approach 1, methods withdraw() and deposit() in Account class should contain their lock/unlock calls on the ReentrantLock instance right? That would free the consumer from dealing with the thread concern. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

> shouldn't the Account's withdraw() and deposit() methods be somehow
>   protected

Actually, when below line executes, then block of code is being guarded by `Lock` object (and each Account object has its own `Lock` object). So, no other thread can execute same code using same `Account` instance.

```
while(true)
    {
      if(from.lock.tryLock()){
        try { 
            if (to.lock.tryLock()){
               try{
          ....
          ....
```

On the other hand, when you are executing the code you are creating multiple `Account` object, which making each transfer independent to each other. As, each `Account` object has it's own state (`balance`, `lock` )

> Also, what if there's a getBalance() method? Should it be protected
>   too

As above.